# Spock Parametrized and Parallel Specification

Tags: spock

here is the use case:

```
class AWSTest{

  def setupSpec() {
    //starts an AWS instance with an specific $version
  }

  def test1() {}   
  def test2() {}

}
```

I have a set of instances versions and I have to run a set of tests on each version.

With TestNG I have been able to create a new instance of AWSTest containing a version (from the set of versions) and then run all the instances of AWSTest in parallel

Is there any way to accomplish this in Spock?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to achieve this particular mode of parallelization in Spock. Perhaps you could create one subclass per AWS instance and instruct your build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle) to run test classes in parallel.